# Ask for Google Chrome Profile for each Window

Tags: google-chrome

I have two profiles in Google Chrome. One for job #1 and another for job #2. For both jobs I use almost same web sites, so I need two Google Chrome user profiles to be able to log in with different user accounts and have active sessions with different user accounts on these websites.

For both jobs I also have to use a few desktop applications which open URLs with default browser. The problem is that when Google Chrome is opened from desktop application it does not ask for user profile and just picks at random (maybe not random, but I do not see any logic so far).

How can I make Google Chrome to always ask for user profile, including when some desktop application opens a URL?

Comment: Not possible. Best I can think of is using 2 different browsers and keep the question "which browser do you want to use open" but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've had similar before, you can get close, but not exactly what you want.   Edit the chrome profiles, and at the bottom, there's an option for create desktop shortcut, so you can open each profile separately.  You can also pin them to the taskbar and give each a different 'avatar' so you can tell them apart.  It's not perfect, but it's close.

Comment: One other thing. I use Vivaldi browser, it had profiles before Chrome did, so its implementation could be different. In Vivaldi, whenever you switch to a different profile, opening a link will always open in the same window you had opened last. So even if you have two profiles open at the same time, if you first switch to the window you want the link to open in, and then click on it, it will open in that profile. Also, as for what profile is opened, in Vivaldi, it opens the last used profile. If you close the browser with 2 profiles open, it will open both of them.